# clang_complete doesn't complete constructors

Tags: c++, vim, clang-complete

Consider this source fragment:

```
class Z
{
  public:
    Z(int){}
    void foo() {}
};
```

This works as intended:

```
int main()
{
  Z a(1);
  a.        // <- at this point, a list of functions appears in a menu
```

This does not work at all:

```
  Z b       // <- at this point, nothing happens if I press <Tab> or C-X C-U
            // except a "pattern not found" message
  Z b(      // <- same here
```

But this does:

```
  Z b = Z   // a list of constructors appears in a menu when <Tab> is pressed
```

Is it possible to set up clang_complete such that the constructor completion works in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `clang` (and `libclang`) issue, not Vim's plugin `clang_complete` issue.

`clang` is now in active development stage AFAIK, so, you can file bug-report at http://llvm.org/bugs . But, I myself filed several bugs related to code completion more than a month ago (e.g. [this one](http://goo.gl/jR5h7)) but they are still unresolved.

When I need to get available constructors list, I write code like yours `Z b = Z`, select constructor, and then convert `Z b = Z` to something I really need. Not very good, but better than nothing.

Comment: I have suspected this. Sigh.